# Strange change in reputation

Tags: support, reputation

Just a few seconds ago I typed in an answer to this question.

[How to use $_GET or $_POST variable to distinguish each type of request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790052/how-to-use-get-or-post-variable-to-distinguish-each-type-of-request)

that type my reputation was 1971

and I deleted my answer for the question after some seconds and some seconds later I found that the reputation now is 1969. I could not see any downvotes still.

I went to check my reputation change feed and couldn't find any record for this.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/674374/mithunsatheesh?tab=reputation

Please help me out

UPDATE:

I checked it with the ***show removed posts*** check box on, and still couldn't find any feed for today.

Comment: You probably had an unrelated suggested edit on a post that was deleted at around the same time.

Comment: @Mysticial: should this be shown in the reputauion tab of my profile?

Comment: Make sure you check the "show removed posts" box at the bottom of your rep page.

Comment: click on `show removed posts` in the reputation page to see the details.

Comment: @Mysticial: Still it doesnt show any reputation change for today. and the change occured only some minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219331/automatic-paypal-process) (10k+) for which you had an approved suggested edit was deleted and factored into that recalc, that's where the -2 came from.

Once you hit the 1k cap from suggested edits though, another suggested edit will take its place in situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me.. I too lost two points unknowingly. It has nothing to do with your deleted answer. A post which brought you points earlier would have been deleted. so the points which you gain from it like edit/upvote/accept will eventually vanish

Comment: click on `show removed posts` in the reputation page to see the details.